# How to find row with the highest value for the day in pandas and gets the categorial percentages?

Tags: python, pandas

Here is my dataset:

```
date               CAT_A     CAT_B     CAT_C
2018-01-01 5:00    12        223       155
2018-01-01 6:00    199       68        72
...
2018-12-31 23:00   56        92        237
```

The data shows every hour for every day of the year. So I want to know in pandas how I can find the highest value row for each day, and then get the categorical percentages at that hour. For example if the highest hour was 5:00 for day 01-01 then CAT_A: 3.07%, CAT_B: 57.2% CAT_C: 29.7%

Comment: What do you mean by highest value row? the sum of all categories?

Comment: @BorutFlis Yes exactly, the sum of all the categories at that row (hour). I need to know for each day which hour generated the highest amount.

Answer (score 1):

We sum the three columns:

```
df["sum_categories"] = df.sum(axis=1)
```

We groupby on daily basis and obtain the index of the max daily row:

```
idx = df.resample("D")["sum_categories"].idxmax()
```

We select the rows with this index and calculate proportion:

```
df.loc[idx,["CAT_A", "CAT_B", "CAT_C"]].div(df.loc[idx,"sum_categories"].values)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`DataFrameGroupBy.idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.idxmax.html) by Series created by `sum` and divide by [`DataFrame.div`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.div.html) filtered rows by [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html), multiple by `100` and round:

```
#if necessary DatetimeIndex
#df = df.set_index('date')

s = df.sum(axis=1)
idx = s.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq="D")).idxmax()
df = df.loc[idx].div(s.loc[idx], axis=0).mul(100).round(2)
print (df)
                     CAT_A  CAT_B  CAT_C
date                                    
2018-01-01 05:00:00   3.08  57.18  39.74
```